# ASP .NET Core IIS Deploy IIS AspNetCore Module Error: CLR worker thread exited prematurely

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

I give IIS every feature in windows, but if your have advice please share me. Anyway I want deploy on IIS Lan server, but I can't. I don't know how can fix this. I use ".net.5.0".
My application codes like that:

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration().UseUrls("http://localhost:8080/")
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
    }  
}
```

Startup

```
namespace EcommerceGastro.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDbContext<GastroDB>();
            services.AddScoped<IMainCategoryService, MainCategoryService>();
            services.AddScoped<IProductService, ProductService>();
            services.AddScoped<ICategoryService, CategoryService>();
            services.AddScoped<IUploadImageService, UploadImageService>();
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfile));
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(opt =>
            {
                opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            //Initiliazer.HomePageControl().Wait();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": { "DefaultConnection": "server=.; database=GastroDB; user id=sa; password=123;" }
}
```

My publish settings:
[image]

My iis settings:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Paylaşılmıyor = Dont share
[image]

Yetkilendirme = authority
[image]

My Error :

```
Application '/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\Users\Tuğçe\Desktop\iisDeneme\EcommerceGastro.API\bin\Release\net5.0\publish\' failed to load coreclr. Exception message:
CLR worker thread exited prematurely
```

```
Application '/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\Users\Tuğçe\Desktop\iisDeneme\EcommerceGastro.API\bin\Release\net5.0\publish\' has exited from Program.Main with exit code = '0'. Please check the stderr logs for more information.
```

And i browse this iis web app its open but look like :

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start
Common solutions to this issue:
The app failed to start
The app started but then stopped
The app started but threw an exception during startup
Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2028265
```

Comment: I think the problem might be in accessing the database. This is very common in such kinds of error messages.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in the error message? It says right there: **"Check the system event log for error messages"**

Comment: A tip for another developers: I got this errror because my connection string has a '/' only. I solved it changing my connection string to SERVER//INSTANCRNAME ( '//')

Answer (score 23):

In my case, the problem was that it was running on a 32bit app pool, but the app was published as `Framework-Dependent` with a target runtime of `win-x64`. When I switched it to `win-x86` my app started working, so then I looked into it and discovered the problem with the app pool. I made a new app pool, disabled 32bit, switched my app to that pool, and republished, and then it worked.

Edited to add: I had a second app display the same behavior for a different reason. In the second case, it was because I was using Serilog to write a log file to the app's root directory. But because the app pool did not have write permissions for that directory, it was failing and throwing the `500.30` error. Granting write permissions for the app pool on its directory solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

For me in a .net 8.0 Web API application, the problem was the last two environment variable entries in the web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="bin\Debug\net8.0\MyAPIApp.Server.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="5000" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES" value="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
          <environmentVariable name="DOTNET_STARTUP_HOOKS" value="c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\professional\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\web tools\projectsystem\Microsoft.WebTools.ApiEndpointDiscovery.dll" />
          <environmentVariable name="APIDISCOVERY_FILEPATH" value="[Specific Drive]:\[My GIT Directory]\MyAPIApp.Server\obj\Debug\net8.0\ApiEndpoints.json" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

`DOTNET_STARTUP_HOOKS` and `APIDISCOVERY_FILEPATH` also have specific file paths which seems odd as this will fail on other machines, unless the setups are the same.

For context, they were not required by my main PC, but whilst also trying to do develep on an old Surface Go it seems the configuration was added automatically by Visual Studio.

Further digging shows it is the latest version of VS, 17.9, that adds these two variables to the config file.

Commenting them out, solves the problem for my PC (version 17.8.6). For the Go laptop, disabling the feature "Use advanced web API endpoint discovery" will supposedly solve one of the issues, further investigation required for the `HOOKS` variable.

Comment: This one was my solution. Somehow the local settings had snuck into the server deploy.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this issue and it turned out to be a bad `appSettings.json` value for my logger. Double check you have entered correct values for your `appSettings.json` attributes.

Answer (score 2):

The most common and easiest way to resolve this error is to re-publish your code, but with the options to "Remove additional files at destination" turned on. This will ensure that Visual Studio’s web deploy process will delete all existing files from the Web App before copying over the new code files. This will result in only the necessary files being published will exist in the Web App file system after the publish has completed. It also ensures that all files are overwritten with the newest versions; in case that may be interfering somehow as well.

To enable the Remove additional files at destination setting, click Edit on the Publish Profile within Visual Studio. The setting is located on the Settings tab underneath the File Publish Options expandable area. Check the box to enable the feature, then click Save.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the target framework to be Portable; instead of x86 or 64; and it succeeded to publish again.

Comment: In my case was the solution. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was just a simple mistake into connection string

Error one `"DefaultConnection": "Server=ADSESERVER101.dom.domain.com\TIMESERVER;..."`

Correct one `"DefaultConnection": "Server=ADSESERVER101.dom.domain.com\\TIMESERVER;..."`

missing `\\` was the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that although Visual Studio is fine with C# style comments in appSettings.json e.g.

```
...},
// this is a comment
"MyValues": {...
```

If they are retained when published to IIS, you may get this error.  JSON is a data-only format by design, though some parsers can ignore comments.  The only "official" way to put a comment in JSON is to format it as data:

```
...}, 
"__comment1__": "this is a comment",
"MyValues": {...
```

However this is still data and will be read by your program along with all the other data, so beware.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the debugging mode (visual studio) just clean the solution will solve the problem.
In the production mode (IIS), first of all, clean the solution, publish the project, and replaced it with the previous one. (Make sure you will delete the whole previous folder and settings as *@Samwu mentioned before*)

Answer (score 0):

In my case just update my code with this:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    
                });
    }
```

---Updating the explanation---

The Main method was without the Function: CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
for that reason my web application sent the error: HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start.
Please take into consideration the below reference:
[Asp .Net Core Main Method](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/asp-net-core-main-method/)!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error caused by a missing registration in Startup.cs. So adding the required registration solved the problem. Eg:
`services.AddScoped<IMissingClass, MissingClass>();`

Answer (score 0):

The problem occured for my ASP.NET core 8 **win-x64** application. I noticed "**Enable 32 bit application=true**" in the app-pool advanced settings. I changed it to false, and it worked.